# Mediaplayer seguir reproduciendo canción aunque este cerrado

Tags: java, android

Quisiera saber si es posible que un reproductor pueda seguir reproduciendo una canción aun si esta cerrado la actividad principal, ya saben como los reproductores populares en donde son cerrado pero siguen funcionando con una notification, he leido y he tratado con un servicio el problema de este es que recrea el servicio cuando se le cierra mas no lo continua exactamente donde lo dejo y hay un pequeño intervalo en donde no hay sonido

Comment: la mejor forma es usar un servicio foreground, es decir se ejecutará en sengundo plano pero habrá una notificación para pausar o cancelar.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu consejo